# Fix leak between seal and shower door joint

Tags: shower, leak

Anyone got any suggestions for sealing this gap up?

[image: gap in seal]
[image: other gap in seal]

The problem is because of the door joint, the top seal can't work all the way down, but the bottom seal can't move all the way flush because when the door opens it pushes it out of the way... leaving a gap that bleeds water.

I'd rather not replace the cubicle but its making our living room ceiling rather wet!

Comment: Is the miracle cure, caulk it, an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could always cut a small piece of urethane or silicone foam (closed cell only) and glue it into the gap on the static side of the opening.  it would act as a live seal that could adapt to the gap or move as the door rotates.

you might want to take some time to really clean the existing sealant/caulk out from all over and redo it.  also do the floor to shower pan joint.  use a good solvent to clean everything up and bleach all surfaces prior to re-caulking.  you have so much filth and mould there that new sealants wont stick.  a properly sealed shower assembly wouldnt let water into your ceiling below even if the door seals are not working.